# How to decode JPX images in java?

Tags: java, pdf, jpeg2000, jpedal

I'm trying to render a pdf (with pdf-renderer or jpedal), and it can't handle an image encoded using JPX. Is there any open-source java library that can decode JPX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPX needs JPEG2000 which needs the JAI and imageIO libraries. JPedal has support for JPX - you just need to enable it which explained on the support section.

There is a patched version of the imageio to fix the memory bug on our site at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2011/03/java-jai-image-io-jpeg2000-memory-leak-fix/

Comment: I had already tried with jai but it didn't work. Then I used your jai-imageio jar instead, and.. it's quite slow but it worked.

ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames() now lists jpeg2000 too.